# javascript: manipulating large hex numbers

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I want to create an excel-like interface with editable fields. Editing those
fields will result in a number that is bit-composed of those fields, for example:

```
field1: bits 0-6, value 0x0F
field2: bits 7-13, value 0x0F
result: 0x078F
```

This is rather easy to do if I wasn't dealing with fields that amount to 100-150 bit results:

```
field1: bits 0-6, value 0x0F
field2: bits 7-13, value 0x0F
field3: bits 14-34, value 0x0F
field4: bits 35-65, value 0x0F
field5: bits 66-96, value 0x0F
...
...
```

making it impossible to use any kind of integer variables. I must somehow store the numbers as long bitstrings but sitll provide bitwise calculations on them. I would like to hear about an approach that could accomplish this.

Comment: Do you want to provide only bitwise operations or also arithmetic operations?

Comment: I think this task only requires bitwise operations

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want bitwise operations, the fields can be stored just as you mentioned them.

Say each number (150 bits) is broken down into `n` fields, then you can store `field1`-`fieldn` for each of your "number".

Now say you have two such numbers and want to do a bitwise operation to get a third such number. Now, bitwise operations work at bit level (ie calculation of one bit doesn't affect other). So you can handle the fields separately.

Now say the operation is bitwise XOR - `^`

You can simply do

```
field1_c = field1_a ^ field1_b
field2_c = field2_a ^ field2_b
```

And so on till n.

This can be applied to any bitwise operation.

For arithmetic operations though you will have to carry between fields.

Addition is pretty simple. (Think how you would do it on paper, how the carries move ahead).

Comment: the end result doesn't have fields, it is just all of the bits combined to one big bit sequence. This changes the values of all the bits in the fields that make it, so operations are not independent of each other

Comment: "This changes the values of all the bits in the fields that make it" why do you think combining the fields to get a huge sequence will change a bit. It will be better if you provide a simple example demonstrating what you need. Your question is really unclear.

Comment: if field1 is bits 0-6 with value 0xf and field2 is bits 8-9 with value 0x1 then the end result is 0x1f, it's 0x8f. so operations on fields are not independent.

Comment: Then what? Please explain your problem correctly. Without it the conversation is going nowhere.

Comment: input is a list of fields, each with its size and value. output should be the bit sequence that is composed out of them. For example: [bits 0-6, value 0xf] and [bits 7-8, value 0x1] should create  result = [bits 0-8, value 0x8f]